# Wordpress starter plugin prevent save to data base after refresh browser

Tags: php, wordpress, caching, browser, plugins

I have 2 questions:

1.In script i send post data from form. After that the data are saved in data base. Everything works OK but when user press "Refresh" button in browser the script saves again the same data . I found that i can use session token but after trying for all weekend I don't know how to do it. The working plugin site http://booword.uk4u.pl/ysp/.

2.I would like to write  plugin for WordPress to use for everyone as a starter script. So my second question is if this script is correct written and how would you do it.

```
<?php
/*
Plugin Name: Yoolek Starter Plugin
Plugin URI: http://yoolek.com/
Description: Yoolek Starter Plugin - simple starter plugin to use with shortcode [yoolek-starter-plugin]
Version: 1.0
Author:
Author URI: http://yoolek.com/
*/
defined( 'ABSPATH' ) or die( 'Plugin file cannot be accessed directly.' );

if ( ! class_exists( 'YoolekStarterPlugin' ) ) 
    {
    class YoolekStarterPlugin {



        protected $tag = 'yoolek-starter-plugin';

        protected $yoo_name;
        protected $yoo_year;

        protected $admin_option1;
        protected $admin_option2;

        public function __construct()
        {       
            /* we will use shortcode [yoolek-starter-plugin] in post or page */
            add_shortcode( $this->tag, array($this, 'run_yoolek' ) );

            add_action( 'admin_menu', array( $this, 'admin_menu' ) );
        }



        public function run_yoolek()
        {
            ob_start();/*to keep content correctly (not under shortcode) look down <?php return ob_get_clean();?>*/


            $this->create_form();
            $this->result();
            return ob_get_clean();
        } 


        /**********************************************************/
        private function result(){
            $this->admin_option1 = get_option("yoolek-starter-plugin-option1");/*admin option*/
            $this->admin_option2 = get_option("yoolek-starter-plugin-option2");/*admin option*/
            echo "admin option 1= ".$this->admin_option1."<br/>";
            echo "admin option 2= ".$this->admin_option2."<br/>";
            global $wpdb; /* save data to database and display*/
            $table_name = $wpdb->prefix . 'yoolek_starter_plugin';


            if (isset($_POST['yoo_submit'])) {
            $this->yoo_name = $_POST["yoo_name"];/* option*/
            $this->yoo_year = $_POST["yoo_year"];/* option*/
            $wpdb->insert($table_name, array(
                "time" => date("Y-m-d H:i:s"),
               "yoo_name" => $this->yoo_name,
               "yoo_year" => $this->yoo_year
            ));
            }
            $result = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM ".$table_name." ORDER BY time DESC");

                echo '<table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-condensed">';
                    echo '<thead>';
                        echo '<tr>';
                            echo '<th>ID</th>';
                            echo '<th>Time</th>';
                            echo '<th>Name</th>';
                            echo '<th>Year</th>';
                        echo '</tr>';
                    echo '</thead>';
                    echo '<tbody>';
                    foreach($result as $row){
                        echo '<tr>';
                            echo '<td>'.$row->id.'</td>';
                            echo '<td>'.$row->time.'</td>';
                            echo '<td>'.$row->yoo_name.'</td>';
                            echo '<td>'.$row->yoo_year.'</td>';
                        echo '</tr>';
                        };
                    echo '</tbody>';
                echo '</table>';         

        }
        /**********************************************************/

        /**********************************************************/
        private function create_form()
        {               
            ?><form class="form-horizontal" action="" method="post">
                <fieldset>


                <legend>Yoolek Starter Plugin Form</legend>

                <!-- Select Basic -->
                <br><br>

                <!-- Text input-->
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label class="col-xs-5 col-sm-3 control-label" for="yoo_name">Name:</label>  
                  <div class="col-xs-7 col-sm-7">
                  <input id="yoo-name" name="yoo_name" placeholder="your name" class="form-control input-md" required="" type="text" value="">

                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label class="col-xs-5 col-sm-3 control-label" for="yoo-year">Your lucky year:</label>
                  <div class="col-xs-7 col-sm-7">
                    <select id="yoo-year" name="yoo_year" class="form-control">
                        <option value="1991">1991</option>
                        <option value="1992" selected>1992</option>
                        <option value="1993">1993</option>
                    </select>
                  </div>
                </div>


                <!-- Button -->
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label class="col-xs-5 col-sm-4 control-label" for="submit"></label>
                  <div class="col-xs-7 col-sm-6">
                    <button id="submit" name="yoo_submit" class="btn btn-block btn-success">Submit</button>
                  </div>
                </div>

                </fieldset>
            </form>
            <br><br>
            <?php 



        }/*html_form*/ 


        /**********************************************************/
        /*ADMIN,PLUGIN HOOKS AND FUNCTIONS*/
        function settings_page() {


            /*update*/
                if (isset($_POST['option_update'])) {
                    check_admin_referer();//Tests if the current request was referred from an admin page
                    $variable1 = $_POST['field_option1'];
                    update_option("yoolek-starter-plugin-option1", $variable1);//update option
                    $variable2 = $_POST['field_option2'];
                    update_option("yoolek-starter-plugin-option2", $variable2);//update option
                    echo "<div class='updated'><p><strong>Yoolek Starter Plugin has been updated</strong></p></div>";
                }

            /**/
        ?><form method="post" action=" <?php admin_url('options-general.php?page=yoolek-starter-plugin.php')?> ">
                <div class="wrap">
                    <h2>YOOLEK STARTER PLUGIN SETTINGS<sup style='color:#D54E21;font-size:12px;'><?php //echo $yoolek_starter_plugin_version; ?></sup></h2>
                <div>
                    <label for="yoo_option1"  style="width:200px; line-height:23px; float:left;">option1</label>
                    <select name="field_option1" id="option1" width="200" style="width: 200px">
                        <option value="option nr1" <?php if (get_option("yoolek-starter-plugin-option1")== "option nr1") { ?>selected="true" <?php }; ?>>option nr1</option>
                        <option value="option nr2" <?php if (get_option("yoolek-starter-plugin-option1")== "option nr2") { ?>selected="true" <?php }; ?>>option nr2</option>
                        <option value="option nr3" <?php if (get_option("yoolek-starter-plugin-option1")== "option nr3") { ?>selected="true" <?php }; ?>>option nr3</option>    
                    </select>
                    <span class="setting-description"> Select option1.</span>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                    <label for="yoo_option2"  style="width:200px; line-height:23px; float:left;">option2</label>
                    <input type="text" width="200" style="width: 200px" size="16" maxlength="12" name="field_option2" id="option2" value="<?php echo get_option("yoolek-starter-plugin-option2"); ?>" />
                    <span class="setting-description"> Enter option2.</span>
                    </div>
                    <p class="submit">
                        <input name="option_update" value="Save Changes" type="submit" class="button-primary" />
                    </p>


                </div>
            </form><?php
        }
        function admin_menu () {
            add_options_page( 'Yoolek Starter Plugin Page', 'Yoolek Starter Plugin Menu', 'manage_options', 'yoolek-starter-plugin', array( $this, 'settings_page' ) );
        }


        static function plugin_activation() {

            /* create table in data base*/
            global $wpdb;
            $table_name = $wpdb->prefix . 'yoolek_starter_plugin';/* name z _*/
            $charset_collate = $wpdb->get_charset_collate();
            $sql = "CREATE TABLE $table_name (
                id mediumint(9) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
                time datetime DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00' NOT NULL,
                yoo_name tinytext NOT NULL,
                yoo_year text NOT NULL,
                UNIQUE KEY id (id)
            ) $charset_collate;";
            require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/upgrade.php' );
            dbDelta( $sql );

            /*create_options*/
            /*add_option( $option, $value, $deprecated, $autoload );*/
            add_option('yoolek-starter-plugin-option1', 'option1Value1', '', 'yes');/*<----------------------------------- Creates new database field */
            add_option('yoolek-starter-plugin-option2', 'option1Value2', '', 'yes');/*<----------------------------------- Creates new database field */
        }

        static function plugin_deactivation() {

                    global $wpdb;
                    $table = $wpdb->prefix . 'yoolek_starter_plugin';
                    $wpdb->query("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS $table");

                    delete_option('yoolek-starter-plugin-option1');/*<----------------------------------------------------------- Deletes the database field */
                    delete_option('yoolek-starter-plugin-option2');/*<----------------------------------------------------------- Deletes the database field */
                }

    }/*class*/  
    new YoolekStarterPlugin;

    register_activation_hook( __FILE__, array( 'YoolekStarterPlugin', 'plugin_activation' ) );/*<------------------------------ Runs when plugin is activated */
    register_deactivation_hook( __FILE__, array( 'YoolekStarterPlugin', 'plugin_deactivation' ) );/*<---------------------------- Runs on plugin deactivation */
}/*if*/?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Quick things that caught my eye at 1st look:

1- Your plugin lacks textdomain

2- You are using "eager init" , i'd recommend 'lazy init'. Read more here: http://hardcorewp.com/2013/initializing-singleton-classes-used-in-wordpress-plugins/

3- You should use wpdb->prepare (esp. when you are inserting data with variables) read more on it on Codex.

4- Your class name could be 'Yoolek_Starter_Plugin' for readability.

5- You are using a lot of hardcoded "yoolek_*" strings. Which is fine normally, but if you want to use it as a generic skeleton plugin to copy and develop multiple plugins, you must think of more generic ways.

There's probably more, these are of the top off my head

Comment: Thank you very much. I need more few weeks to understand all your suggestions:). I found example of such code iand i will try to improve mine.